# Unity OmniSharp with VS Code - Omnisharp error: "Project Loading Failed"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

**The Problem**

Intellisense / Autocorrect is not working in Visual Studio Code. I believe this to be because the target framework can not be found by Omnisharp.  Note this image:

[image: Visual Studio Code Image]

You can see the yellow error on the bottom ribbon. You can also see in this image that I've set the TargetFrameworkVersion to 4.8 manually, it was saying 4.7.1 earlier.  I tried 4.7.1 and it still wasnt working so I reinstalled 4.8 and set it manually.

Clicking on the yellow text shows me this error:

`Error: Build started. Project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj" (ResolvePackageDependenciesDesignTime;_GenerateCompileDependencyCache;CoreCompile target(s)): Building with tools version "Current". The target "ResolvePackageDependenciesDesignTime" does not exist in the project. Done building project "Assembly-CSharp.csproj" -- FAILED. Build FAILED.`

If anybody has any information on how to fix this I would be very grateful.

Comment: You could switch the bottom "Output" to show the "Omnisharp Log" output, there may be interesting errors there.

Answer (score 0):

In VS code in the c# extention,
try to untick this option :
[image]

Or that a look at this article
https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runtimes/unity/